# iPhone opengl es: Orthographic projection depth

Tags: iphone, graphics, opengl-es

Hi guys I am working on  opengl es on the iPhone. What I am trying to achieve is the effect similar to a series of boxes stacked 1 behind the other. The boxes are of different heights. I am using orthographic projection to get this effect. However all of my boxes appear stuck to each other. It seems that the depth value is not having any effect. In an nut shell my code to create these boxes is

// I define the orthographic space from 0.01 to 1000 and I iteratively create the boxes at depth -1,-4,-6,-8

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Got any images of what you are getting? What you expect/want?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not set up a depth buffer. See this question on how you set up one: [Request a DepthBuffer in OpenGL ES for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361516/request-a-depthbuffer-in-opengl-es-for-iphone) .

However it might be convenient to just sort the boxes on every game update and render them from back to front.